# Angular2 HTTP Post - Hitting the Service but no payload

Tags: c#, json, angular, angular2-services

I am trying to post to my back end service to delete some records. Right now I can hit the controller method on the backed but the parameters are null. (Our backed is a .NET CORE API). I notice in the dev tools that when I make the call I am getting a 204 No Content message.

I am not sure if this is a problem with my back end or front end.

Component Method that initiates the post:

```
    delete(): void {
        this._contactService.deleteEmail(this.multipleRecords) 
            .subscribe(s => { this.isSuccessful = s; },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

API Call in Angular Service:

```
    deleteEmail(emails: IMutlipleDelete[]): Observable<boolean> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this._http.post( this.url, JSON.stringify({emailList:emails}), options)
            .map((response: Response) => <boolean>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

^ Here, I have tried different content types, I read online that the COORS policy doesn't accept "application/json" as a content type, but even if I change the type, the same result occurs.

And lastly my back end Method: (This is were my parameter is null)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool EmailDelete(string emailList)
    {
        return _contactEmails.DeleteEmailRecords(emailList);
    }
```

In my "DeleteEmailRecords" method would deserialize the json object into the model that I need to delete. However, it never gets there because my initial parameter emailList is null.

I've tried several different things with my back end method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool EmailDelete(string[] emailList)
    {
        return _contactEmails.DeleteEmailRecords(emailList);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public bool EmailDelete(EmailDeleteModel[] emailList)
    {
        return _contactEmails.DeleteEmailRecords(emailList);
    }
```

Where `EmailDeleteModel` is the same model as `IMutlipleDelete` ~ just called a different name on the back end.

Most recently I tried this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool EmailDelete([FromBody]EmailDeleteModel[] emailList)
    {
        return _contactEmails.DeleteEmailRecords(emailList);
    }
```

Still my parameter is not coming across, but am hitting the breakpoint in the method.

I've also tried different ways to set up my body, such as:

`JSON.stringinfy(emailList:emailList);` ~ and a ton of variations of this.

I also resorted to just try and passing a string as the emailList:

```
    let emails: string = "Dog";
    JSON.stringify({ emails})
```

But the 204 No Content is still an issue.

EDIT: Added a `Console.Log(JSON.stringify({ emailList: emails })` (This is my `IMultipleDelete`) for clarity:

```
    {"emailList":
       [{
         "type":"Personal",
         "envelopeSalutation":"NANCY WALKOWIAK",
         "entityId":40075275,
         "affiliation":1,
         "toDelete":true,
         "accountId":5004528
       }]
    }
```

Is their just something I am missing? Or am I way off base?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You’re passing a stringified array to the Api, which is expecting a string. Because of that, the Api will attempt to serialize the JSON to a string, and fail, leaving you with a null parameter value. Maybe change the Api parameter data type to `string[]`, and see if that helps. What is an `IMutlipleDelete`, a string?

Comment: Originally I had my controller method set up to handle a list of objects, but i was still getting the error: `EmailDelete(List<MultipleDelete> emailList)`

Comment: Then try a basic array, rather than a list. The type mismatch is likely the issue.

Comment: Trying right now

Comment: Okay. We may still need more information on what a `MutlipleDelete` is.

Comment: Multiple Delete is Model that holds account and email IDs to pass to the server to be deleted.

Comment: And by changing my `public bool EmailDelete(string[] emailList)` I got a string array to come over! but the inside was null, so progress.

Comment: Getting closer. Was there any count in the array? How about `MutlipleDelete[]` then?

Comment: Changing it to `MutlipleDelete[]` gave me an list of `MutlipleDelete[0]` when the paremeter comes over the wire. I am `console.log(emailList)` on the front end and it is populated.

Comment: Can you add the output of the `console.log(emailList)` to you question?

Comment: Added it to the question, keep in mind that this is only one record, but I could potentially be passing in multiple of these due to the way the system is set up.

Comment: About the only other thing I can think that could cause this is if the names of the fields in the JSON are not getting matched to the names of the properties in the `MutlipleDelete` class/object. The names and types match (except for the camel/Pascal casing)?

Comment: Yes the objects inside the Model match (except on the angular side camel case). The only difference is the name of the model. On the angular side the model is called `IMutlipleDelete` and on the c# side its called `EmailDeleteModel`, does that make a difference?

Comment: In all honesty, I have never tried this where the object names were different, so I can't say for sure, but I wouldn't think it would matter. The schema is the important part. I thought we had this for a minute, too!! :)

Comment: I did too, I feel like I am closer to a resolution. I think you for your time and help. I am starting to think perhaps my back end isn't configured correctly, because from everything I've read it seems like it should be working. Thanks again :)

Comment: One more thing to try. Change your API function signature to something like this: `EmailDelete([FromBody]MutlipleDelete[] emailList)`. The `[FromBody]` is sort of important here.

Comment: Nadda :| , Could versioning be an issue here?

Comment: You may want to change the post call back to the way you had it before, too. `return this._http.post( this.url, JSON.stringify(emails), options)...`. Don't wrap the value you're passing in an object ({...}).

Comment: You are a legend. Worked like a charm. If you move your reply to an answer ill mark it as correct

Comment: Excellent!! and done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your API function signature to something like this:

```
EmailDelete([FromBody]MutlipleDelete[] emailList)
```

The `[FromBody]` is important here.

And, You may want to change the post call back to the way you had it before, too.

```
return this._http.post( this.url, JSON.stringify(emails), options)...
```

Don't wrap the value you're passing in an object (`{...}`)